# Do I apply my proficiency bonus to a cantrip attack for a Sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, attack, cantrips, spellcasting

I decided to through the Firebolt cantrip into the "Attacks and Spellcasting" box on the character sheet. I understand I use my Char modifier, but do I also apply a proficiency bonus as well to the Atk bonus? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NeonKraken For reference, have you tried reading the [DNDBeyond entry for sorcerers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer) or the [D&D 5e basic rules](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf)? Or the [linked questions on this site](/questions/51306)?

Comment: I've already read through the sorcerer guide. I'm not really concerned about the actual attacking process, moreso what to put on my page.

Comment: In the attack box, I am putting the "Firebolt" cantrip as on attack, so i am wondering how I calculate the attack bonus or if there is any at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For cantrips and other spells, both the spell save DC and spell attack modifier include proficiency bonus.

If you check the [sorcerer's Spellcasting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer), it tells you how to calculate your spell save DC and your spell attack modifier.

> Spell save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier
>
> Spell attack modifier = your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier

Your character's proficiency bonus is included in both formulas.

[Cantrips are spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100302/do-cantrips-benefit-from-spell-attack-modifiers). When you make an attack roll as part of a sorcerer spell, then it's a [spell attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51306/how-do-i-calculate-if-a-spell-hits-and-how-much-damage-it-does), so you roll a d20 and add your [Spell attack modifier](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48415/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-spell-attack-modifier), comparing the total versus their AC.  However, the proficiency bonus is *not* usually included in  damage rolls.

Similarly, if a sorcerer spell requires the target to make a saving throw, then the target would roll their saving throw (d20 + some modifiers) against your spell save DC.